# Do the level layouts vary when "visiting previous levels"?

Tags: risk-of-rain

Every level has several layouts, and only certain layouts contain Artifacts. If at first you got a level layout that **didn't** have an Artifact, is it possible to get the right layout by visiting it on a second lap (aka "Visit previous levels" as the teleporter message names it).

Comment: Yes, this can happen.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can actually get a different level (i.e. Ancient Valley vs Sunken Tombs) on the reruns, not just different layouts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not having played with the new update, I cannot be 100% sure, but based on previous knowledge I would say yes, as layouts are randomly generated to a degree every visit.

Comment: I will test with the new update now

Comment: Okay, I played through a game and I can give 100% assurance that stages to re-generate when moving back to previous levels, meaning artifacts could spawn.

Comment: The play of my laps, first pass through I had the forest, and second I had the beach, so I can, in my experience, assure that layouts can be different. I didn't find any artifacts though, they may just be extremely rare.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand you, did you play all the way to ancient temple, then instead of going to the spaceship level you went to the beginning by pressing "A" on the final teleporter, right?

Comment: I did, I played through as quickly as a could and return to the first level at the final teleporter.

Comment: Odd. Our tests seem to have yielded different results. Sorry, but I think I'll wait for someone else to try it out.

Comment: @user1337 Yes, the levels are regenerated every time. It is incredibly unlikely that you got the same set of levels 3 times in a row. Maybe your game just broke (this is a rather buggy game). I know from personal experience that revisiting previous levels regenerates them.

Comment: @jw013 Well thanks for the confirmation. Played another endless run. 3 laps, the usual. The only level that changed was the frozen bridge one, and I got the artifact there. Magma barracks, same layout 3 times in a row as well.